# SwiftUI gestures in the toolbar area ignored

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I'd like to implement a custom slider SwiftUI component and put it on the toolbar area of a SwiftUI Mac app. However the gesture of the control gets ignored as the system's window moving gesture takes priority. This problem does not occur for the system UI controls, like `Slider` or `Button`.

How to fix the code below so the slider works in the toolbar area as well, not just inside the window similar to the default SwiftUI components?

[image: sliders]

```swift
struct MySlider: View {
    @State var offset: CGFloat = 0.0
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { gr in
            let thumbSize = gr.size.height
            let maxValue = (gr.size.width - thumbSize) / 2.0
            let gesture = DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0).onChanged { v in
                self.offset = max(min(v.translation.width, maxValue), -maxValue)
            }
            ZStack {
                Capsule()
                Circle()
                    .foregroundColor(Color.yellow)
                    .frame(width: thumbSize, height: thumbSize)
                    .offset(x: offset)
                    .highPriorityGesture(gesture)
            }
        }.frame(width: 100, height: 20)
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var value = 0.5
    var body: some View {
        MySlider()
        .toolbar {
            MySlider()
            Slider(value: $value).frame(width: 100, height: 20)
        }.frame(width: 500, height: 100)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like design limitation (or not implemented yet feature - Apple does not see such view as user interaction capable item).

A possible workaround is to wrap you active element into button style. The button as a container interpreted as user-interaction-able area but all drawing and handling is in your code.

Tested with Xcode 13.2 / macOS 12.2

*Note: no changes in your slider logic*

[image: demo]

```
struct MySlider: View {

    var body: some View {
        Button("") {}.buttonStyle(SliderButtonStyle())
    }

    struct SliderButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
        func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
            MySliderContent()
        }

        struct MySliderContent: View {
            @State var offset: CGFloat = 0.0
            var body: some View {
                GeometryReader { gr in
                    let thumbSize = gr.size.height
                    let maxValue = (gr.size.width - thumbSize) / 2.0
                    let gesture = DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0).onChanged { v in
                        self.offset = max(min(v.translation.width, maxValue), -maxValue)
                    }
                    ZStack {
                        Capsule()
                        Circle()
                            .foregroundColor(Color.yellow)
                            .frame(width: thumbSize, height: thumbSize)
                            .offset(x: offset)
                            .highPriorityGesture(gesture)
                    }
                }.frame(width: 100, height: 20)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the added `.contentShape(Circle())` and `.gesture(TapGesture().onEnded{})`? They seem superfluous.

Comment: true, that left from test findings - just remove them